# how to clear up redis entries periodically?

Tags: redis

Using a map of hash of my entry to epoch timestamp. Over a day, the map accumulates about 5 million entries and takes up too much memory. 80% of entries are not updated frequently and I want to delete those entries with epoch timestamp updated in last 24 hours. The clean up can happen weekly to avoid the map growing out of bounds over time.

I tried setting TTL on entries but it causes slowness in performance in redis lookups and inserts. I was thinking of maintaining a sorted set by an hour to hashes, but that will take up more space and I am not sure if the value set can be that large to contain millions of hashes. What are some of the better approaches to handle this cleanup?

Comment: Can you describe the "slowness"?

Comment: average latency of reads/writes increases 2-3 fold affecting our system SLIs. In general, I dont think TTL is designed for so many entries as TTL cycle will take a lot of time.

Comment: TTL for so many entries also causes increased memory fragmentation leading to high  memory usage